# Using rpm update firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, rpm

What command do I run in order to update firefox using rpm?
I have been asked this question and am not aware how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perhaps could do this using your distro's software updater, but suppose you've got FF's installer (rpm) file and also suppose that it's called firefox.rpm.  You should then do:

rpm -Uvh firefox.rpm

If you don't have any previous FF version installed on your computer you might as well do:

rpm -ivh firefox.rpm

Comment: `-U` works for installs as well as updates and, historically at least (I don't know if this is still true), had much better general behaviour.

Comment: @Etan, you're absolutely right about -U.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have `yum` configured on rpm based systems (`RHEL or Fedora`) you could simple run the below command, this would download and update the dependencies, instead of just updating only a single firefox rpm.

```
`yum update firefox`
```